# How to fix 'Line Length Violation: Line should be 120 characters or less' - SwiftLint

Tags: swift, swiftlint

How to fix Line Length Violation?

Relevant part of alert message that isn't allowed due to Line Length Violation:   `message: NSLocalizedString("\nYou will be requested to Use %@ to Sign In. %@ doesn't share any information about you. The permission is required to post your Live Video.",` **⚠ Line should be 120 characters or less: currently 208 characters (line_length)**

Comment: This looks like a SwiftLint message.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, and don't know how to fix it

Comment: Well, shorten the line or disable the warning (clearly explained at https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/blob/master/README.md#disable-rules-in-code)

Comment: @matt the same way, the question seems to be hard to understand, Martin did answer it though

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Make the line shorter:

```
message: NSLocalizedString(
    ["\nYou will be requested to Use %@ to Sign In. ",
    "%@ doesn't share any information about you. The ",
    "permission is required to post your Live Video."].joined()
)
```

or better, using vacawama's multi-line solution:

```
let message = 
    """

    You will be requested to Use %@ to Sign In. \
    %@ doesn't share any information about you. \
    The permission is required to post your Live Video.
    """
```

That's a generic solution, but isn't really appropriate for `NSLocalizedString` because it breaks tools that scan for localized strings like `genstrings`.

Your other solution is to turn off the warning for that line by adding a disable on the line immediately before:

```
// swiftlint:disable:next line_length
```

See [Disable rules in code](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/#disable-rules-in-code) for full details on disabling swiftlint rules.

Comment: If you end the lines with backslash it won't introduce newlines.

Comment: @vacawama whoa… I didn't know that. That's awesome.

Comment: Disabling linting rules is never a good solution. If you start doing that, there is no point in having a linter in the first place. The root problem is the fact that localization tools want you to use the default message as the localization key. There is no point in putting the whole message in code, a simple string code, e.g. "sign_in_info' would work too.

Comment: I disagree that disabling linting rules is never a good solution. If that were true, they would be compiler errors. The fact that we separate even warnings from linting is intentional. Linting is intentionally over-strict. Even Go, where things as benign as failure to use a variable is a compile-time error, there is still a linter (govet) that is sometimes correct to ignore. The correct choice between shortened localization keys versus using automated tools has no universal answer. Saying "the linter forbids using Apple's localization tools" is a foolish consistency.

Comment: (I say this as a long-time advocate for there being a "1 true Swift style" such that clang-format would enforce exactly one way lay out Swift code. Even if I'd had my way, there would be times to ignore a linter. http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5886836526284800)

Comment: `// swiftlint:disable:next line_length` is the answer we found best

Answer (score 35):

In this case just update your `line_length` rule with `ignores_interpolated_strings` like this:

```
line_length:
  warning: 120
  ignores_function_declarations: true
  ignores_comments: true
  ignores_interpolated_strings: true
  ignores_urls: true
```

and make sure you are using last version of `swiftlint` (it was [added](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/commit/ac9b5348e133a58d19c9b021530ff18ef462d33f) just a few weeks ago)

Comment: Not ignoring comments.

Comment: it's not working :( it try to put the same in .yml file and again same warning still appear only the following is working so far line_length: 200  which i don't want for all line

Comment: warning is not  going by ignores_interpolated_strings this thing

Comment: Still not working

Comment: Where i can find this file .swiftlint.yml? I have installed through brew commands, will this in be my project folder as hidden? –

Answer (score 4):

**This line added in .swiftlint.yml rule file its works for me**

```
# implicitly 
line_length: 110
```

Comment: Where i can find this file .swiftlint.yml? I have installed through brew commands, will this in be my project folder as hidden? –